# Understand a type as another

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a class `A` and a class `B`.

```
class A {
    public void foo1(){ print("foo1"); }
    public void foo2(){ print("foo2"); }

    ...
    public void fooN(){ print("fooN"); }
}

class B {
    public A a;
}
```

When I call `B`, I'd like it to behave as if it was an instance of `A`, so I could do this:

```
B b = new B();
B.a = new A();
B.foo1();
```

How can I achieve this behaviour? I tried to add this function in `B` but it didn't work:

```
public static implicit operator A(B instance) { return instance.a; }
```

PS: `A` cannot be inherited from.

Comment: I don't think there is a clever way, e.g. if you look at the framework [HttpContextWrapper](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Abstractions/HttpContextWrapper.cs), which is pretty much doing this, then it lists all the methods explicitly with stubs that just call the wrapped object. Unless something's been added in a new C# version since then.

Comment: How many types similar to `B` are you planning on having? You could use the Decorator or Proxy design patterns for this.

Comment: I just want this specific case, no more classes involved.

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? It won't get you anything, because you cannot use `B` where `A` is expected, since C# is not duck-typed. If you are trying to extend `A` by overriding its methods, but it does not mark them as `virtual`, then you can re-declare them on `B` using the `new` keyword - but this probably won't work either since the code calling `A.Method()` will not use your "overridden with new" `B.Method()`.

Comment: errr, what wrong with inheritance?  `class B : A { }`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, `A` cannot be inherited from. This was really the first thing I tried before asking. This would be the perfect behaviour, but unfortunately I cannot inherit from `A`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `B.foo1()` change class B to :

```
class B
{
    public void foo1() {
      if(a!=null) a.foo1();
    }
    .........
    .........
    public A a {get; set;}
}
```

Any other way you will not be able to compile your code. `b.foo1()` will give a compiler error. You can use reflection and call something like `b.aMethod("foo1")` but it is a different story.